# List Index out of bound

Tags: soql, error, indexing

I have below code which throws List index out of bound error.

I am not getting where i do wrong here.

**Code**

```
String Territory= '\''+ (String) p.get('Primary_Territory_vod__c')+'\'';
        system.debug('Franchise@@@'+Franchise);


List<Territory> terr =[select Id, name , ParentTerritoryId  from territory where name =:Territory];
```

Comment: check again. this code looks fine to me. error comes from other pieces of code... somewhere you must be using index of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a LIMIT statement in the SOQL query, which is usually not a smart thing.
And do you iter over the "terr" results?
When "terr.size()" would return 0, and you try to get the first record "terr[0]", then you could expect this error.

See also: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181121&type=1

Comment: SOQL Limit not required here as OP is fetching a specific Territory by name